# HTML dogleg tables?

Tags: html

I'm trying to recreate an old text in HTML. At one point, the text does something kind of funny: it has two columns of text, and when one column reaches its end, the other column begins spanning the entire page.

Here is a mock example I've created in Paint:
[image]

Is there a way to do this with tables in HTML? Thanks.

Comment: Tables? Why would you want to do this with tables?

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do it. Everyone here is recommending CSS, but I know nothing about CSS.

Comment: CSS is a particular way of adding style properties to elements on the page by selector. You need CSS in this case. Don't be afraid; tables would be way, way harder and introduce all kinds of other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. See: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/jj7Bh/

It's a bit hard to see the effect with the narrow page size on jsFiddle, but that's how you do it - just set some CSS styles on paragraph #1.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without CSS? I'm not very familiar with it. Thanks.

Comment: You should want to do it right, which means you need to use Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).

Answer (score 1):

No.  You don't want tables, you want css float.

Example CSS:

```
.container {width:600px}
.inset {float:left; margin:0 20px 20px 0; width:300px}
.standard { }
```

Example structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inset"></div>
    <div class="standard"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pja6T/)

Answer (score 0):

Floating the short paragraph left should do it:

```
<p id="short-paragraph">Lorem ipsum…</p>
<p id="long-paragraph">Vestibulum…</p>
```

With the CSS:

```css
#short-paragraph { float: left; width: 40%; padding: 0 2em 2em 0; }
```

Comment: As I do in the jsFiddle, you need to set the short-paragraph's width to something or nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this with tables. Do it with a floated `<p>` with a specified width. Here is an example that I just validated in Safari:

```
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
</style>

<p class="box">
Box of text...
</p>

<p>
This text wraps around the bottom of the other text...
</p>
```